# Run a java file using JUnit in Eclipse through command terminal

Tags: java, junit, testng, appium, testng-eclipse

I am new to automation using Appium. So while using Eclipse i created a TestSuite.java file which includes all of my test cases.I want to run this file using JUnit in eclipse through **command terminal**.Please help me with command in mac.

I am using macOs. I am adding some screenshots of my project.

(1) *This is my project in eclipse*

[image: [1]]

---

(2) *This is my TestSuite.java file*

[image: [2]]

(3) **Output after running**

> mvn surefire:test - 
>   DrunSuite=com.appium.automation.MobileGesturesRevised/TestSuite.class

Output: [output in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFc82.png)

(4) pom.xml file

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q00D.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think I see a pom.xml in the screen shot so you can run

```
mvn surefire:test -DrunSuite=com.appium.automation.MobileGesturesRevised/TestSuite.class
```

You can just create a new run configuration for that under the Eclipse run menu.

Comment: I used this command in my terminal after changing directory to my project.

Comment: I have added the snapshot of output too so please refer to (3) point above

Comment: The class names of the unit tests have to end in ...Test. Otherwise they will not get picked up by Maven.

Comment: i did not get you sir can you explain?

Comment: You have to rename the class SetUp to SetUpTest, Scroll to ScrollTest etc. That is why the AppTest does get executed and the other is not.

Comment: Can i see the results of these tests?

Comment: I think you might have an odd mix between Unit 4 and 5. Have you added the Junit 4 dependency manually to the Eclipse project (not via the pom.xml)?

Comment: This might be the problem. You should have added unit as a dependency to the pom.xml with the <scope>test</test>. Can you add the pom.xml to the original post? And what happens if you remove junit4 from the project.

Comment: i have added above please refer to that.